# Gradle build can not find properties in parent gradle.properties files

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have multiple project gradle build and I am trying to externalize dependencies version via `gradle.properties`. Unfortunately child project can not find properties in parent `gradle.properties`

So in parent `gradle.properties` I have:

```
SPRING_VERSION=3.2.0.RELEASE
```

in parent `build.gradle` I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$SPRING_VERSION"
    ...
```

and this works fine. But in the child project same thing cause error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 
Could not find org.springframework:spring-context-support:$SPRING_VERSION.
```

If I hardcode the version project builds fine.

also in parent file I have `settings.gradle` which specifies:

```
include 'projectA','projectB','projectC'
```

project structure

```
root
|
\ buildSRC
\ projectA
    |
    \ build.gradle
\ projectB  (build script in parent build.gradle)
\ projectC  (build script in parent build.gradle)
|
|
\ build.gradle
\ gradle.properties
\ settings.gradle
```

Comment: Can you show the full/exact error message, and perhaps also the stack trace? Perhaps you have accidentally used single quotes in the subproject?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser : You were right , I used single quotes in the child project. Didn't know there is a difference. If you care you can add it as an answer and I will accept that. Thanks!

Comment: It's a Groovy thing, the difference being that only double-quoted Strings support String interpolation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Groovy, double-quoted Strings support String interpolation, whereas single-quoted Strings don't. Apparently, you mistakenly used a single-quoted String in the subproject. As a result, Gradle went searching for a version that is literally named `$SPRING_VERSION`, which of course it didn't find.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately neither of the other options worked out for me.  I had had success referencing the variables in this file using the following.

```
project.getProperties().SPRING_VERSION
```

Maybe this will help someone else.

Answer (score 4):

Verify if inside your child project you have settings.gradle and if it's there, remove.

Answer (score 2):

In projectA-build.gradle you should reference the variables in main gradle.properties with this code:

```
project.SPRING_VERSION
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither compile 'org.springframework:spring-context-support:$project.SPRING_VERSION' nor ...support:project.SPRING_VERSION does not work

Comment: Try: compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: project.SPRING_VERSION

Comment: That worked out for me, with Gradle 6.8.2.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue. If the projects are built from parent directory. The gradle will find `gradle.properties`. But if you issue build command from child project, gradle process starts from that location, so it has no way of knowing common properties defined in root project.

The gradle build configuration doesn't have something similar to maven

```
<parent>...</parent>
```

element. so it fails to read properties.

So I think the best way is, if you want to build all projects, issue gradle tasks from root project location.

if you want to build specific subproject, issue something like this below from parent location.

```
gradle :subproject:anygradletask
```

Comment: This works when you are building locally. But how to configure the same in jenkins? when people commit child module changes, its failing as it cannot find those properties which were actually defined at parent's location gradle.properties.  Can't find a way to achieve this.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a root project **gradle.properties** file content by:

`${project.PROPERTY_NAME}`

I mean, for your example it should be:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${project.SPRING_VERSION}"
    ...
```

And don't forget to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

*(I know this is an old post, but I guess it can help someone who are looking for solution)*