# Does Gradle support properties interpolation?

Tags: gradle

I can't find the syntax of property interpolation in gradle.properties:

```
prop1 = value
prop2 =${prop1}/lib
```

Is it supported at all ?
Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`gradle.properties` is a plain Java properties files, hence String interpolation isn't supported. I recommend to keep all user-defined properties in `build.gradle` or a separate build script, which provide a much richer configuration language. For example:

gradle/properties.gradle:

```
ext {
    foo = "foo"
    foobar = "${foo}bar".toUpperCase()
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply from: "gradle/properties.gradle"

println foobar
```

Comment: I arrived here looking for an interpolation answer but my strings were defined using single quotes and so I didn't find a complete solution until I saw [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20013868/1707353). You may want to cite your earlier answer in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, string interpolation isn't supported cause gradle properties is a plain properties provides key=value syntax. But you can implement interpolation.

My implementation:

```
println("Gradle properties preprocessor : running")

val properties = Properties().apply {
    load(FileInputStream(
       File(rootProject.rootDir, "gradle.properties")
    ))
}

fun interpolate(propertyValue: String): String {
    var interpolatedPropertyValue = ""

    propertyValue
        .split("[\\[\\]]".toRegex())
        .forEach { variableName ->
            val variableValue = properties.getProperty(variableName) ?: return@forEach

            println("Gradle properties preprocessor : found $variableName variable")

            interpolatedPropertyValue = interpolate(
                propertyValue.replace(
                    "[$variableName]",
                    variableValue
                )
            )
        }

    return interpolatedPropertyValue.ifBlank { propertyValue }
}

val interpolatedProperties = properties.mapValues { interpolate(it.value.toString()) }

for (project in rootProject.childProjects.values) {
    println("Gradle properties preprocessor : setting variables for ${project.name} project")

    for (property in interpolatedProperties)
        project.setProperty(
            property.key.toString(),
            property.value
        )
}

println("Gradle properties preprocessor : finished")
```

It's supports multi-project projects.

You can see my implementation in action on [github](https://github.com/KartoshkaPy/space.vyazem/blob/master/build.gradle.kts). 
 Link may can broken at now (when you reading this).

Then you can do something like that:

```
kotlinVersion=1.6.10

kotlinWrappersVersion=pre.290-kotlin-[kotlinVersion]
reactVersion=17.0.2
reactWrapperVersion=[reactVersion]-[kotlinWrappersVersion]
reactRouterVersion=6.2.1
reactRouterWrapperVersion=[reactRouterVersion]-[kotlinWrappersVersion]
styledComponentsVersion=5.3.3
styledComponentsWrapperVersion=[styledComponentsVersion]-[kotlinWrappersVersion]
```

Use [propertyName] syntax to include a property within another property.

I think that it's can be helpful for someone who reading this in the future.
Cause I leave it here.